# Why can't my programs find resource files when using bazel run //package

Tags: c++, bazel

I apologise if the title is a bit vague - I didn't know how else to phrase it.

I am quite new to Bazel but one thing that I don't quite understand is why my program fails to find the resource files I specify using the data attribute for the cc_binary rule

For context I am trying to follow Lazy Foo's SDL2 tutorials and I have a directory structure somewhat like this

```
gltuts
|
+---lazy-foo-02
|   |
|   +---media
|       |
|       +---hello_world.bmp
|
+---lazy-foo-03
```

Here is what my BUILD file looks like inside of the lazy-foo-02 directory

```c
cc_binary(
name = "lazy-foo-02",
  srcs = [
    "main.cpp",
  ],
  data = glob(["media/*"]),
  deps = [
    "//subprojects:sdl2",
  ],
)
```

When I use the bazel run command (I use bazelisk)

```sh
bazelisk run //lazy-foo-02
```

I get an error saying my hello_world isn't found. I managed to find an executable in bazel-bin (well a symlink to the executable somewhere in the .cache/bazel/... directory structure.

Now the directory where the symlink is located has the media directory and when I execute from this symlink location, it works as expected.

Why would this not work using the bazel run command? Am I missing anything from the BUILD file?

I am happy to provide more information if needed.

Thanks

Comment: The compiled executable is somewhere else. In order to work around that, see Bazel "runfiles".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [C++ runfiles library](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/runfiles/runfiles_src.h) to find them. Add the dependency in your BUILD file:

```py
cc_binary(
  name = "lazy-foo-02",
  srcs = [
    "main.cpp",
  ],
  data = glob(["media/*"]),
  deps = [
    "//subprojects:sdl2",
    "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp/runfiles",
  ],
)
```

and then where your code needs to find the file:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "tools/cpp/runfiles/runfiles.h"

using bazel::tools::cpp::runfiles::Runfiles;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string error;
  std::unique_ptr<Runfiles> runfiles(
      Runfiles::Create(argv[0], &error));

  if (runfiles == nullptr) {
    return 1  // error handling
  }

  std::string path =
      runfiles->Rlocation("gltuts/lazy-foo-02/media/hello_world.bmp");
}
```

See [the header file](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/runfiles/runfiles_src.h) for API docs and some notes on how to handle child processes, accessing them without `argv[0]`, etc. `@bazel_tools` is a special repository name which is automatically provided by bazel itself, so no need for any `WORKSPACE` changes.